# How to explicitly load a LAZY fetching member of a hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

Due to performance concern I have make most of the relation mapping in hibernate as `fetch = fetchType.LAZY` to avoid unnecessary query to the db.

```
....
private ConsumerEntity consumerEntity;

@ManyToOne(fetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="orderId", insertable=false, updateable=false)
public ConsumerEntity getConsumerEntity(){
    return this.consumerEntity;
}
....
```

Above shows the mapping setting of relation for `OrderEntity` and `ConsumerEntity`.

Each time the callers do a query, I will open a session, process the query and return them the result, then close the session.

```
Public OrderEntity getOrderEntity(orderQueryParam){
   Sting hql = buildHqlStrFromParam(orderQueryParam);
   return (OrderEntity)this.getEntityByHql(hql); // in the method just 1. open a session; 2. retrieve entity 3. close the session;
}
```

But **sometimes** I know caller may need the related records as well. Like, if he ask about a specific Order record, I may want to give him the consumerEntity as well, so He can just do a *dot* thing to get the information he needed, and won't have to process a second query or get a lazy-loading-exception because the session has been closed:

```
  ...
  OrderEntity order = TradeService.getOrderEntity(orderQueryParam);
  ConsumerEntity consumer = order.getConsumerEntity();
  ....
```

But the scenario is very rare so that I don't want to change the `fetchType` to `EAGER`.

How to do this? I mean I want to have a choose whether or not loaded the `ConsumerEntity` which was configured as `fetchType.LAZY`.

Comment: You can reason that this is a common requirement and thus several duplicate questions must already exist. So which similar questions did you find and why do they not answer yours? Because I already see a few winners in the "related" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a boolean check to load the consumer entity if that flag is true than call getter method, It will load your lazy data into the object and will available further.

```
Public OrderEntity getOrderEntity(orderQueryParam, boolean loadConsumerEntity){
    Sting hql = buildHqlStrFromParam(orderQueryParam);
    OrderEntity entity = this.getEntityByHql(hql);
    if(loadConsumerEntity){
      // Your session shoud still open here
      entity.getConsumerEntity();
    }
    return entity; 
}
```

Comment: Don't use session in getEntityByHql other wise getter method will throw error. Do the session open and close activity in getOrderEntity method.